# ultraedit find quote and replace

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I have a row that looks like this:

```
'ABCD','ABKCKD','ADFL','3','43
```

In UltraEdit, I am trying to find `'3'`,' and replace that as `3`,
I tried to find as `['][\d]+['][,][']` and found `'3','`

However, when I tried to replace it as `[\d]+[,],` it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `'(\d+)','` and replace with `$1,'`

Comment: `'3','43` ... why does 43 have a missing right quote?

Comment: I just ignored the last quote. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to capture the number between the quotes, you can do it like this using capturing group `()`:

```
'([\d]+)','
```

then use the captured digit using `^1` so your replace would be : `^1,`

Ultraedit regex usage [reference](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: It properly captures the part that I want. However, when I tried to replace it, it literally shows $1 instead of just the digit

Comment: try this `^1`, also in find use `^(` & `^)`

Comment: ultraedit mentions using `^1` instead of `/1`, ref : https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/regular-expressions.html

Comment: also you should try replacing `'3'` with `3` and not `'3','` with `3,` as it won't for the last number, if any.

Answer (score 0):

*UltraEdit* has support for 3 different regular expression engines:

- **Perl** ... the most powerful regexp engine using Boost Perl regexp library.
- **UltraEdit** ... the native regexp engine of UltraEdit with syntax like in Microsoft Office.
- **Unix** ... UltraEdit regexp engine with Perl regexp syntax (more or less).

The IDM power tip [tagged expressions](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/tagged-expressions.html) explains the usage of marking/capturing/tagging groups on running an **UltraEdit** regular expression replace.

The IDM power tip [Perl regular expressions: Backreferences](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/perl-regular-expressions-backreferences.html) explains the usage of marking/capturing groups on running a **Perl** regular expression replace. This syntax can be also used for legacy **Unix** regexp engine with limited capabilities.

`[`...`]` defines a character class/set, i.e. a list of characters. Any character within the square brackets can or must be found for a positive search. Using a character set does not make much sense for a single character like `'` and `,`. It is possible to use `['][\d]+['][,][']`, but it is much easier to use as search string `'\d+','`.

Please note that the escape sequence `\d` in a **Unix/Perl** regexp search string defines a characters set for **any digit**. The equivalent in an **UltraEdit** and by chance also in **Unix/Perl** regexp search string is `[0-9]`.

The replace can be done with search string `'^([0-9]+^)','` and replace string `^1,'` on using **UltraEdit** regular expression engine.

The replace can be done with search string `'(\d+)','` and replace string `\1,'` on using **Unix** or **Perl** regular expression engine.

With the **Perl** regexp engine it is also possible to use for this replace the search string `'(\d+)'(?=,')` with replace string `\1` because of `,'` is specified in a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which does not match/select characters.